# count all items within a dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary, count

my question is:
I have a dictionary with one object for each character of the alphabet. Within those objects, there are all values for a specific character.

Example:

```
alphabetDictionary
  a
    apple
    alien
  b 
   balloon
   ball
```

I now want to count all entries within this dictionary:

```
apple
alien
balloon
ball
-> 4
```

Using this sourcecode only counts the objects (a, b, etc)

```
NSString *counter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Entries (%d)", alphabetDictionary.count];
```

So how do I get all entries and not the objects a,b,etc?

EDIT 1:
In the viewDidLoad Method I have:

```
//Initialize the array.
charDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
alphabetArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if ([charSpecialArray count] > 0)   {

    //Set object for this character within the dictionary
    [charDict setObject:charSpecialArray forKey:@"#"];
    //fill the alphabetArray with an index value, if this char exists at all
    [alphabetArray addObject:@"#"];
}

if ([charAArray count] > 0) {

    [charDict setObject:charAArray forKey:@"A"];
    [alphabetArray addObject:@"A"];
}
```

etc.. for each character

followed by:

```
totalCounter = 0;
//Count all keys within the Dictionary
for (id objectKey in charDict.allKeys) {
    totalCounter += [[charDict objectForKey:objectKey] count];
    NSLog(@"Anzahl: %d", totalCounter);
}   
NSString *counter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TXNs (%d)", totalCounter];

self.title = counter;
```

the results are looking much too high:

- Character H has 33 entries
- the count of H characters results in: 132
- m characters: 1587
- m characters count: 6348

Any ideas why those counts are this high?

Comment: Are you surely H really only has 33 entries?

Comment: If the # is too high, it is because you have more elements than you expect in the arrays contained within the dictionary.  Since you haven't shown your data source, there is no way to help further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is:
I've used NSInteger instead of NSUInteger

Answer (score 3):

a, b, etc. are keys. The arrays [apple, alien], etc. are objects.

To get the total count, you need to loop through the dictionary and sum it up:

```
NSUInteger total = 0;
for (NSString* key in alphabetDictionary) {
  total += [[alphabetDictionary objectForKey:key] count];
}
return total;
```

Or use this very slow one-liner:

```
int count = [[[d allValues] valueForKeyPath:"@sum.@count"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSEnumerator *aEnum = [alphabetDictionary objectEnumerator];
id object;
NSUInteger count = 0;
while( object = [aEnum nextObject] ){
 count += [object count]; // assuming that the object is an array
}
NSString *countStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Entries (%ld)",count];
// %d NO ofcourse not its not a NSInteger we want a Long
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocFastEnumeration.html):

```
NSUInteger count = 0; 
for (id objectKey in alphabetDictionary.allKeys) {
    count += [alphabetDictionary objectForKey:objectKey].count;
}
NSString *countStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Entries (%ud)", count];
```

Comment: Well.. the counting itself works.. but anyhow the number I get is much too high..
I've updated my question...

Comment: I'm not sure what would be wrong with code, honestly. I would do test cases with a dictionary that has a small set of known objects in it.

Comment: the problem was I used NSInteger instead if NSUInteger

Comment: Daniel, if you solved the problem, please do one of the following: a) post an answer of your own, and select it b) select someone else's answer, c) delete the question (if, in the end, you think the solution was trivial, and the question is not relevant to anyone else)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to delete this question because of the votings and all the answers.
So here is my own answer to the question why the number of counted entries where so high:

I used NSInteger instead if NSUInteger

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same in Swift. I had a `Dictionary`of `arrays`. Resulting in the following code:

```
var totalItemsOfAllPages:Int {
    var totalItemsCount = 0

    loadedPages.values.array.map({
        totalItemsCount += $0.count
    })

    return totalItemsCount
}
```